# Display featured products on top of display

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am working on opencart and fetching a list of products using below mentioned query and these products are displayed with most recent product on top.

```
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"select p.image,p.price,p.store_name,p.deal_title_url,p.shop_now_url,p.coupon_code,p.special_deal_txt,p.special_comment_txt,s.price,d.name,p.date_added from oc_product p, oc_product_special s,oc_product_description d where p.product_id=s.product_id and p.product_id=d.product_id order by p.date_added DESC $limit;");
```

Note - 
1. Limit is for pagenation
2. Data is fetched from multiple tables

Now i want to display all the featured products on top of the display. So basically the products which are in featured array must always be displayed on top and then remaining products based on the creation date.

The featured product id's are kept in an array - $featured_array

How can this be done?

Note that number of featured products may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UNION. In first query get featured products, in second put your current query. Limit is for union result

```
(
select p.image,p.price,p.store_name,p.deal_title_url,p.shop_now_url,p.coupon_code,p.special_deal_txt,p.special_comment_txt,s.price,d.name,p.date_added from oc_product p, oc_product_special s,oc_product_description d where p.product_id=s.product_id and p.product_id=d.product_id AND p.product_id IN($featuredProductsIds) order by p.date_added DESC 
)
UNION
(
select p.image,p.price,p.store_name,p.deal_title_url,p.shop_now_url,p.coupon_code,p.special_deal_txt,p.special_comment_txt,s.price,d.name,p.date_added from oc_product p, oc_product_special s,oc_product_description d where p.product_id=s.product_id and p.product_id=d.product_id order by p.date_added DESC 
)
$limit;
```